# VB Read file and set combobox.text value with text file value

Tags: vb.net, combobox, text-files

I have a configuration file with some saved values:

> COM Port=COM4
>
> Baud Rate=
>
> Bits=
>
> Parity=
>
> Stop bits=
>
> Mode=
>
> CRC Byte=

When I load my Form I would like to read the txt file and write the values to a Combo Box to initialize the form values.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim ConfigFile As String
            Dim Path As String
            Dim WriteText As String
            Dim ConfigVal As String()
    
            ' MsgBox("Form Load")
            Path = Application.StartupPath
            'ConfigFile = Path + "\ComConfig.txt"
            ConfigFile = "C:\Users\wlowe\Documents\ComConfig.txt"
    
            ' If' Not System.IO.File.Exists(ConfigFile) = False Then
            '   System.IO.File.Create(ConfigFile).Dispose()
            'End If
    
            ' Load Configuration values
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(ConfigFile, True)
            WriteText = objReader.ReadLine()
            COMCombo.Text = WriteText
            'MsgBox(objReader.ReadLine().ToString)
            ConfigVal = WriteText.Split("=")
            MsgBox(ConfigVal(1))
            COMCombo.Text = ConfigVal(1)
    
            WriteText = objReader.ReadLine()
            BaudRateCombo.Text = WriteText
            BitsCombo.Text = objReader.ReadLine()
            ParityCombo.Text = objReader.ReadLine()
            StopBitsCombo.Text = objReader.ReadLine()
            ModeCombo.Text = objReader.ReadLine()
            CRCCombo.Text = objReader.ReadLine()
            objReader.Close()
End Sub
```

But when the form is loaded, the values for each combo box are blank.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Set a breakpoint see where it fails...

Comment: When I add a break point, I see that the 'COMCombo.Text = ' statement isn't working. But I don't know why.

Comment: Set a breakpoint before that and see what value it is...

Comment: I copied-and-pasted your code into Visual Studio and it appears to work exactly as you intend: I see "COM4" in the first combo box.  The only thing that I changed was that I removed the blank lines in your sample config.txt file.